# How do I limit z-axis rotation in unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm writing a 2d game for android. I have a character that rotates from 180 to - 180 degrees. But I need to limit transform rotation by z to 50 and -50. I know it's possible via Math.Clamp(), but I can't apply it. Please help me!!
Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    private Camera myCam;
    private Vector3 screenPos;
    private float angle0ffset;
    private Collider2D col;
    private void Start()
    {
myCam = Camera.main;
col = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
       
    }
    private void Update()
   {
     
Vector3 mousePos = myCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
   ( (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
 
screenPos = myCam.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
Vector3 vec3 = Input.mousePosition - screenPos;
angle0ffset = (Mathf.Atan2(transform.right.y, transform.right.x) - Mathf.Atan2(vec3.y, vec3.x)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
 
   }
      }
  ( (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
   {
 
  if(col == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(mousePos))
    {
      Vector3 vec3 = Input.mousePosition ;
      float angl = Mathf.Atan2(vec3.y, vec3.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
      transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,0, angl + angle0ffset);
     
    }  
     
  }
     
           }  
    }
```

Comment: Rotate the GameObject around its own z-axis in Unity. Using "transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1));" method is valid.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, indeed, use `Mathf.Clamp()`. What you would do is:

```cs
rotationZ = Mathf.Clamp(transform.localRotation.z, -lookZLimit, lookZLimit);
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationZ, 0, 0);
```

In your case your `rotationX` would be:

```cs
rotationZ = Mathf.Clamp(transform.localRotation.z, -50, 50);
```

And then to apply the newly calculated rotation:

```cs
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationZ, 0, 0);
```

Note: this has to be done in `Update()`.